# Change of scalars and field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Does someone know a reference in a textbook for the following fact?

> Let $k \subseteq k'$ be an algebraic field extension and $A$ a $k$-algebra such that the extension of scalars $A \otimes_k k'$ is an integral domain.  Then $\mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}(A\otimes_k k') = \mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}(A)\otimes_k k'$ where $\mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}$ denotes the field of fractions.

The proof is not hard (e.g., $\mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}(A)\otimes_k k'$ $= (\varinjlim_q A[\frac{1}{q}])\otimes_k k'$ $= \varinjlim_q (A[\frac{1}{q}]\otimes_k k')$ $= \varinjlim_q (A\otimes_k k')[\frac{1}{q}]$ injects in $K' := \mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}(A\otimes_k k')$, contains $K := \mathop{\mathrm{Frac}}(A)$ and contains $k'$, and since $k'$ is algebraic it contains their compositum, but clearly that $K'$ is generated as a field by $K$ and $k'$ so it is the same).  But I'm surprised that I can't seem to find it explicitly written anywhere.